# can we change something in gitversion to always return a 2 digit major version?

Tags: gitversion

We have the pipeline yml file autogenerate our software part number using the git version info. We are having a problem with the number of digits and I'm not sure how/of we can implement the logic in the file to fix it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM5UH.png)

we need to pad the major version with a 0 if it is below 10 so that it is always 2 digits.
this is generated by the gitversion step in the build process

The line belowcalls gitversion,it generates a json object as an environment variable

```
   displayName: "Set Controls Version Number in controlsversion.json"
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: echo "$CONTROLSVERSIONNUMBER" && echo "$CONTROLSVERSIONNUMBER" >> $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/WCSW_NA/dbt/CONFIG/controlsversion.json
    env:
      CONTROLSVERSIONNUMBER: '{ "major": "$(GitVersion.Major)", "minor": "$(GitVersion.Minor)", "patch": "$(GitVersion.Patch)","label": "$(GitVersion.PreReleaseLabel)", "version": "$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)", "branch": "$(GitVersion.EscapedBranchName)" }'
```

```
Below  lines  uses that major version to generate the software part number


 GITVERSIONNUMBER: '{ "major": "$(GitVersion.Major)", "minor": "$(GitVersion.Minor)", "patch": "$(GitVersion.Patch)","label": "$(GitVersion.PreReleaseLabel)", "version": "$(GitVersion.FullSemVer)", "branch": "$(GitVersion.EscapedBranchName)", "build_type": "$(BUILD_TYPE)", "sw_part_number": "$(ENTITY_PREFIX)-$(QUALITY_LEVEL)-$(SOFTWARE_FAMILY)$(HARWARE)$(EQUIPMENT_FAMILY)$(GitVersion.Major)$(GitVersion.Minor)" }'
```

we need it to always be 2 digits in length though.?

Tried :

I am not sure but that can be done by applying the if condition in yaml. like if [[ $GitVersion.Major <= 10 ]]; then GitVersion.Major=0; fi